# Can't mount anywhere but to /mnt

Tags: mount, usb, opensuse

My system has developed a strange defect after a distribution upgrade
(OpenSuSE 12.3 -> 13.2). I have various USB devices that I want to
mount to different top-level directories: the backup drive to /backup,
my USB stick to /usb, and the SD card adapter to /SD. That used to
work without problem by simply naming the device ID and the top-level
directory in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1TOSHIBA_TransMemory-part1                        /usb       vfat     noauto,user,exec               0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000LM003_HN-M201RAD_S34RJ9AFA36173-part1        /backup    ext4     noauto,user,exec               0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_MS_PRO_20120926571200000-0:0-part1 /SD        exfat    noauto,user,exec
```

Now, with the new kernel (3.16.7) and all, the exact /dev/disk/by-id
identifiers have changed, so I adapted them, but mounting fails
nevertheless. It turns out I can mount none of these devices to their
preferred mount points anymore, not even when I give the real name (e.g.,
/dev/sdc1 or the like). Mounting them manually, even as root, gives no
output and returns 0 just like a normal mount, but it doesn't populate
the moint point with the content of the disk, and in fact the `mount`
command claims that the device isn't mounted after all.

However, I *can* mount any of these devices successfully if I choose
the mount point /mnt, or, weirdly, a subdirectory of /mnt. That's
reassuring - it proves that there isn't a hardware or driver problem -
but I'd really like to mount my peripherals to their mnemonic names,
and in particular I'd sometimes like to mount two of them
simultaneously.

Why on Earth would the system care *where* I mount something, as long
as the mount point exists, is accessible, and isn't already mounted?
All three top-level dirs worked fine under the old kernel (3.7.10), and
now they don't. Can I be running into some new security manager or filter
rule that I've never heard about?

Comment: You should run the mount command under `strace` to see what it is doing and file a bug report with OpenSuSE including that information.

Comment: @psusi I **have** run `mount` under `strace`, and the output seems identical (excluding different addresses being returned for allocations), right until the exit with code 0. That's why I assume that there's some other (perhaps auto-mounting?) functionality interfering with my manual mount command that I don't even know about.

Comment: May that be the case because of your fstab being broken ? I see missing information...

Comment: **Yikes!** I can't remember whether those trailing numbers are actually missing, or whether I just mispasted. I'll have to check when I get home. Could a broken `fstab` cause this? And why would `/mnt` still work - is there a hardcoded exception for that somewhere?

Comment: If this may help: I run opensuse 13.1, kernel 3.11.10, and I can manually mount /dev/sda1 to /windows . Maybe try other kernel flavors? (I use the -desktop one.)

Comment: So it actually makes the mount() system call, and it does not return an error code?  The last two number columns can be omitted and are ignored on modern systems anyhow using systemd or upstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it!

It's [AppArmor](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:AppArmor), which SuSe Linux now activates by default. It's supposed to add capability-driven security on top of the traditional permissions-based security model, and in its default configuration it disallows all mounts except very specifically described ones, among them `/mnt`. Once I got rid of AppArmor, my mounts work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your underlying question, but I can offer you a workaround.

1. Create a set of subdirectories under `/mnt`, one per device.
2. Replace each "real" and preferred directory, eg `/usb`, with a symlink to the relevant directory under `/mnt`
3. Fix up `/etc/fstab` correspondingly.

Not ideal but it will get you back up and running while you look for a true solution

Comment: I thought of that, but I'd like to understand what's going on. I thought using `/mnt` for mounting things was a pure matter of convention and *technically* as good as any other path. What kind of system component might treat `/mnt` different from other values? I haven't found anything in my `/etc`.

Comment: @Kilian, SElinux, perhaps?

Comment: Would SElinux confess it to me when it prevents things it considers unsafe, or is that classified information?  'Cause I'm not seeing any trace of it in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @Kilian sorry, but I don't know.